# Are installHandlers executed after the LMA creates the license?

Tags: appexchange, lma

I have an app on the appexchange, when a subscriber installs the app, it will run an install handler process on his org.

LMA will also create a license for the subscriber on my org.

My question is:

Are this 2 processes sequential? Can I be sure that The license will be already created when the user runs his post-installation process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have much of experience around managed package development, but going through the documentation, it looks like you don't need a *license* for a User to execute the post installation scripts but it always runs as a special system user representing your package. I would think this to be the correct behavior because scripts are utilized to perform post-installation configs specific to your app for that Organization and not specific to any particular User.

Excerpt below from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm) (emphasis mine):

> **It runs as a special system user** that represents your package, so all operations performed by the script appear to be done by your package. You can access this user by using UserInfo. You will only see this user at runtime, not while running tests.